# Help with enterprise library validation results

Tags: .net, enterprise-library

I'm trying to use Entlib 4's validation blocks but I'm running into a problem clearly identifying invalid properties in the validation results.

In the following example, if the City property fails validation I have no way of knowing whether it was the City property of the HomeAddress object or the WorkAddress object.

Is there a simple way to do this without creating custom validators, etc?

Any insight into what I'm missing or not understanding would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
public class Profile
{
    ...
    [ObjectValidator(Tag = "HomeAddress")]
    public Address HomeAddress { get; set; }

    [ObjectValidator(Tag = "WorkAddress")]
    public Address WorkAddress { get; set; }
}
...
public class Address
{
    ...   
    [StringLengthValidator(1, 10)]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I created a custom validator that extends the ObjectValidator and added a _PropertyName field which gets prepended to the keys of the validationresults.

So now the usage in the example described above would be:

```
public class Profile
{
    ...
    [SuiteObjectValidator("HomeAddress")]
    public Address HomeAddress { get; set; }

    [SuiteObjectValidator("WorkAddress")]
    public Address WorkAddress { get; set; }
}
```

The validator class:

```
public class SuiteObjectValidator : ObjectValidator
{
    private readonly string _PropertyName;

    public SuiteObjectValidator(string propertyName, Type targetType)
        : base(targetType)
    {
        _PropertyName = propertyName;
    }

    protected override void DoValidate(object objectToValidate, object currentTarget, string key,
                                       ValidationResults validationResults)
    {
        var results = new ValidationResults();

        base.DoValidate(objectToValidate, currentTarget, key, results);


        foreach (ValidationResult validationResult in results)
        {
            LogValidationResult(validationResults, validationResult.Message, validationResult.Target,
                                _PropertyName + "." + validationResult.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

And the necessary attribute class:

```
public class SuiteObjectValidatorAttribute : ValidatorAttribute
{
    public SuiteObjectValidatorAttribute()
    {
    }

    public SuiteObjectValidatorAttribute(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
    }

    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    protected override Validator DoCreateValidator(Type targetType)
    {
        var validator = new SuiteObjectValidator(PropertyName, targetType);
        return validator;
    }
}
```